# Вывод модуля в joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Как вывести модуль joomla в компоненте? Например в файле com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php? Есть ли какие-нибудь функции вывода модулей?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="позиция модуля"  style="row" />
```

Comment: Разве так не выводится ?

Comment: Так выводиться в шаблоне, а нужно в компоненте

Answer (score 0):

```
$module_avto = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_catalog');
$params = new JRegistry;
$params->loadString($module_avto->params);

$params->set('path', $this->path );
$params->set('typeview', 'marks' ); 

$module_avto->params = $params->toString('JSON');

echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module_avto);
```